# Is buying from the Apple website VS Apple Store any different?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I am interested in buying the new Apple MacBook Pro 15''. I wanted a somewhat *personalized* version though (500 GB SSD / 16 GB ram) which is not the "basic" one.

My question is this: does the Apple Store have all kinds of combinations, hence buying from the website or from the physical store is identical, or the Apple Store has only the "basic"/default configurations and if you want more (e.g 500 GB SSD vs 128 default one) you have to buy online?

Comment: There is only one place you can buy it, it is the Apple store. Show me the Apple web site where you can buy it!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it is not different.

On apple store you can customize:

In you case it will come up as

Configure your 15-inch MacBook Pro with Retina display

```
2.5GHz Quad-core Intel Core i7, Turbo Boost up to 3.7GHz
16GB 1600MHz DDR3L SDRAM
512GB PCIe-based Flash Storage
Intel Iris Pro Graphics and NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M with 2GB of GDDR5 memory
Backlit Keyboard (English) & User's Guide
```

Comment: Sorry, but didn't got your answer. If I go to a physical store and tell them "I want a MBP 15'' with 500GB, 16GB Ram, etc" they have boxes with these specific characteristics or is this something that you can only do online, while in the store you can only buy the "standard" macbook pro?

Comment: Sorry, we had some misunderstanding. Apple Store is the on line one. Apple Shop is the one you walk in :) I am sure Apple shop can get you what you need, even if they do not have it in they stockroom. The computer you want is not so special that they would have to special order it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean is there a difference between buying over the web and in-store. Buying over the web allows you to configure your system to suit your needs, I did this when buying a Retina display Mac Book Pro 13". Apart from that there are no differences: you can still go to the store for service etc. Hope this helps.